# How often do employers for computer science careers require college degrees?

Tags: employer

By require degrees, I mean they won't consider applicants who have no degree.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad since this will vary depending on the job, the locale, the current cycle in the ebbs and flows of the job market...  in my experience, about 10% on average won't even consider you for any professional position.

Comment: It's going to depend on the applicant pool available and how much time the company has to devote to the search (among other things). If they have a lot of resumes flooding in, they'll surely filter on degrees just to lighten the load.

Comment: A "computer science" career? What is that? Most people I know are software developers, not computer scientists.

Comment: @ Stephan Branczyk Careers involves computer science, I mean.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk unless the term was misused there are actually plenty of computer science jobs out there, I mean they typically involve algorithmic research,  90% of the work being done at the moment in the field of quantum computing is more computer science as opposed to engineering. The typical workflow / job is more like what a biologist or physicist. The majority of jobs would be in acedemia,Also a important distinction is also computational science ( which is what I studied ) which is the field of writing software for the purpose of solving scientific problems from non computing fields .

Answer (score 4):

Great question, and one people without a great educational background often worry about. I'll paste my previous response to you in your other thread:

It really depends on the company in question. Most colleges these days aren't teaching you the skills required to be a software developer without extensive on-the-job training.

Some companies recognize this and prefer self-taught programmers because they don't have to spend a long time unlearning decades of outdated information. That, however, usually depends on how up-to-date your university is. From my perspective, a majority of universities seem terrible for IT. On the other hand, some companies are adamant about you having a degree.

Most job advertisements allow for a degree, `or relevant experience`. So really, what you need to do is find a way to get your foot in the door.

In order to get your foot in the door, I'd suggest learning how to be a front-end, and a back-end developer, and try to turn yourself into a Full Stack Engineer. For example, here's a couple of different paths you could take:

- `C#`, `ASP.NET`, `SQL Server`, `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, `jQuery` on `Windows`
- `PHP`, `MySQL`, `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, `jQuery` and `Linux`/`Windows`

In-between those, throw in a couple extra languages such as `Java`.

Create projects -- any projects -- and make them good. Then you'll have something to show your potential future employer. Learn how to use source control such as git, and how to make yourself as useful as possible, so you require little training.

Employers will see those projects, and if they're good, they'll most likely be willing to take a chance on you.

If you're not going to get a degree, you'll need to work 10x harder, but you'll be a better developer in the end.

Answer (score 2):

What are you actually after here?  In other words are you seeking permission to *not* go to college?  If so, that's a really Bad Idea(tm).

Are you trying to justify to others that you don't need a degree?  You could just go start your own company and set your own rules on who you want to hire.

The simple answer is that you can certainly you can get a job without a degree.  However that's not the question you should be asking because it's unimportant.  The real question is "How much *harder* is it going to be to get a job without a college degree?"

To answer that all you need to do is search the job boards (monster, career builder, etc).  Look at how many positions are open and what the requirements are for them.  I think you'll pretty quickly come to the conclusion that perhaps completing your college education is a Good Idea(tm).

Now if you are writing a paper on this, then you shouldn't depend on a bunch of random internet people to tell you what's what.  Instead go to the source - those job boards I mentioned.  Sift through the posted openings and record what you see.